# Achieve optimal gaussian blur effect in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd, gaussianblur

I am using **kivy & kivymd** and I am trying to achieve an optimal way to apply a gaussian blur to a **FitImage** that stands as a background image.

Naturally, I tried the **EffectWidget**, however, this is not *optimal* considering the fact that I animate it and I want the user to be able to resize the window and according to the docs, the effectwidget recreates the fbo every time there is a change to the widget.

The code I used:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
#:import ew kivy.uix.effectwidget
EffectWidget:
    effects: ew.HorizontalBlurEffect(size=12.0), ew.VerticalBlurEffect(size=12.0)
    FitImage:
        source: "images/song_img.jpg"
# the rest of my code...
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

So I assume the only appropriate way for me to achieve what I want is to alter the **glsl code**.

The glsl code for **ew.HorizontalBlurEffect**:

```
effect_blur_h = '''
vec4 effect(vec4 color, sampler2D texture, vec2 tex_coords, vec2 coords)
{{
    float dt = ({} / 4.0) * 1.0 / resolution.x;
    vec4 sum = vec4(0.0);
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tex_coords.x - 4.0*dt, tex_coords.y))
                     * 0.05;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tex_coords.x - 3.0*dt, tex_coords.y))
                     * 0.09;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tex_coords.x - 2.0*dt, tex_coords.y))
                     * 0.12;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tex_coords.x - dt, tex_coords.y))
                     * 0.15;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tex_coords.x, tex_coords.y))
                     * 0.16;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tex_coords.x + dt, tex_coords.y))
                     * 0.15;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tex_coords.x + 2.0*dt, tex_coords.y))
                     * 0.12;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tex_coords.x + 3.0*dt, tex_coords.y))
                     * 0.09;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tex_coords.x + 4.0*dt, tex_coords.y))
                     * 0.05;
    return vec4(sum.xyz, color.w);
}}
'''
```

According to the docs, the **AdvancedEffectBase** could help with such things, however, the problem is that I have no idea how to change these glsl codes in a way to achieve what I want.

I tried using others' glsl codes for applying a gaussian blur effect like these:

[Shadertoy's code for gaussian blur effect](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xltfzj#)

[Mattdesl's code from github](https://github.com/Jam3/glsl-fast-gaussian-blur)

and others...

How am I supposed to achieve what I want?

**UPDATE:** @Tshirtman's answer seems to be the best one so far, however, I personally ran into a problem with it.

I use the blurred image in a separate screen and the image does not seem to follow the transition animation of the screenmanager, instead it just shows up while the other widgets slowly come into place. Is this fixable? Also, is there a way to up the resolution of the blur? It kind of seems low res.

My Code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import RenderContext
from kivymd.utils.fitimage import FitImage
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class BlurredBackgroundImage(FitImage):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        fs = '''
        $HEADER$

        uniform vec2 resolution;

        void main(void) {
            int radius = 4;
            vec2 d = float(radius) / resolution;
            for (int dx = -radius; dx < radius; dx++)
                for (int dy = -radius; dy < radius; dy++)
                    gl_FragColor += texture2D(texture0, tex_coord0 + vec2(float(dx), float(dy)) * d);

            gl_FragColor /= float( 4 * radius * radius);
        }
        '''
        self.canvas = RenderContext()
        self.canvas.shader.fs = fs
        super(BlurredBackgroundImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.canvas['projection_mat'] = Window.render_context['projection_mat']
        self.canvas['modelview_mat'] = Window.render_context['modelview_mat']
        self.canvas['resolution'] = list(map(float, self.size))
        print("size changed")

    # tried updating the shader whenever the position changes but still no improvements
    '''def on_pos(self, *args):
        self.canvas['projection_mat'] = Window.render_context['projection_mat']
        self.canvas['modelview_mat'] = Window.render_context['modelview_mat']
        self.canvas['resolution'] = list(map(float, self.size))
        print("pos changed")'''


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        name: "main-menu"
        Button:
            text: "Go to next Page!"
            on_release:
                root.transition.direction = "down"
                root.current = "song-view"
    Screen:
        name: "song-view"
        RelativeLayout:
            BlurredBackgroundImage:
                source: "images/song_img.jpg"
            Button:
                text: "Return to main menu!"
                size_hint: .25, .25
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                on_release:
                    root.transition.direction = "up"
                    root.current = "main-menu"
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t want to use an FBO, I think you should not use EffectWidget, but rater directly create your shader on a RenderContext, and bind the texture you want to use as a background to that, so the shader can lookup pixels in it

There is a multitexture example in the repository we can use as a starting point

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/c28c47b39ae57c97c70cc0398d74774d73a6894b/examples/canvas/multitexture.py

I would think something like this (untested).

```py
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import RenderContext


fs_multitexture = '''
$HEADER$

uniform vec2 resolution;

void main(void) {
    int radius = 4;
    vec2 d = float(radius) / resolution;
    for (int dx = -radius; dx < radius; dx++)
        for (int dy = -radius; dy < radius; dy++)
            gl_FragColor += texture2D(texture0, tex_coord0 + vec2(float(dx), float(dy)) * d);

    gl_FragColor /= float( 4 * radius * radius);
}
'''


kv = """
<BackgroundBluredImage>:
    canvas:
        Color:
        Rectangle:
            # the shader will apply where the widget draws, so we need a rectangle of the appropriate size/pos
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            # binding the texture to it so we can look it up in the shader and do our thing
            source: "Coast.jpg"

FloatLayout:
    BackgroundBluredImage:
"""


class BackgroundBluredImage(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.canvas = RenderContext()
        self.canvas.shader.fs = fs_multitexture
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # We'll update our glsl variables in a clock to run every frame, but you could bind it to relevant events only, like size and pos
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_glsl, 0)

    def update_glsl(self, *largs):
        # This is needed for the default vertex shader.
        self.canvas['projection_mat'] = Window.render_context['projection_mat']
        self.canvas['modelview_mat'] = Window.render_context['modelview_mat']
        self.canvas['resolution'] = list(map(float, self.size))


class BluredBackgroundApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BluredBackgroundApp().run()
```

Comment: I don't believe that your code is correct. Can you update it?

Comment: ok, there were a few issues indeed, fixed now, i did a very basic blur shader, feel free to improve.

Comment: your answer seems to work fine when the widget is resized but not for when it is animated. I use this blurred image in a different screen and the widget does not follow the animation like the other elements. I updated the question for more info